# Screen Scraping with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am a newbie in RoR. I want to develop a rails app, which could search flight info from my rails app, fetch the flight informations from various airlines sites(for example; airasia and malaysia airlines).  display those results back in my rails app.
My search module should include the following textfields:

```
From: Kuala Lumpur
To: Dubai
Departure Date:2/11/2009
Return date: 19/11/2009
Departure Time: 12:00
Number of tickets: 2
```

user gets to enter the information above on my site and
a script should search flights according to that information on various airlines sites and
display the results with the tag of which airlines is providing this flight.

Can either use "Scrapi" or "Scrubyt"

Comment: Do you have a specific question or do you want someone else to write t all for you?

Comment: i just want a guide line on hw to start, bt i dont mind if u can write it for me.

Comment: While some developers might frown on scraping, the reason your question was downvoted wasn't because scraping is bad, but because you don't seem to know what you are doing. You're showing us plain text as an example. Screen scraping involves using actual html source code to select elements via their attributes and attribute values. You can use plain text to inform a scrape script, but its always going to need more than that viz. context in terms of tags ("div"), attributes ("id"), values ("id=3"), &/or text ("..>sdfd</a>"), . Research the watir-webdriver gem.

Answer (score 5):

> can anyone offer an assistance?

**Don't.** Find another get rich quick scheme. Or at least don't rely on screen scraping.

There's so much potential for it to go wrong. Find another way to get the information to aggregate. Use API's if they exist and store the schedules in the databases (they rarely change on a week to week basis). Storing things locally makes things faster for your customers, it also allows you to provide more services.

Here are just a few of the potential problems with screen scraping:

- Minor updates to the sites you're scraping can break your tool.
- Scraping attempts from your server's IP can be denied.
- Depending on the information, you could possibly even get sued.

Answer (score 2):

To start with scraping, you can refer to the post -

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-ruby-screen-scraper-using.html 
(Simple Ruby Screen Scraper using Mechanize, Hpricot and XPath )

http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/04/simple-ruby-screen-scraper-in-just-5.html
(Simple Ruby Screen Scraper in just 5 lines without using XPath )

This is just for understanding

Answer (score 0):

*cough cough* watir-webdriver (gem)

the DOM cannot hide